# Git: pushing amended commits

Tags: git

I am currently working on a project and using machines in two different locations to do it. I have created a branch for the feature I am working on and when I finish some work on it I amend my commit to that branch and push it to the server so I can pick up where I left off on my other machine.

When I try to send my amended commit it rejects my push. I assume this is because I am pushing up a commit that is intended to clobber the current HEAD of the feature branch. I typically just use --force.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
mike@sleepycat:~/projects/myproject$ git pull origin topx
From heroku.com:myproject
 * branch            topx       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
mike@sleepycat:~/projects/myproject$ git add app/models/reward.rb
mike@sleepycat:~/projects/myproject$ git commit --amend
[topx 82a9880] Added topX reward
 9 files changed, 106 insertions(+), 21 deletions(-)
 rewrite app/views/ceo/_reward_criteria.html.erb (96%)
 create mode 100644 public/javascripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js
 create mode 100644 public/site/javascripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js
 create mode 100644 public/stylesheets/jquery.multiselect.css
mike@sleepycat:~/projects/myproject$ git push origin topx
To git@heroku.com:myproject.git
 ! [rejected]        topx -> topx (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myproject.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no way to overwrite remote branch without --force in this case. You have 2 options:

- continue to use `git push --force`
- don't use `--amend`. If some work you've done deserves a separate commit (is stable enough, compiling, passing more tests, etc...), create new commit. If not, create temporary branch (something like `my-feature-unstable` if your branch is `my-feature`) and commit there. When it becomes stable again, you can do `git reset --soft my-feature`, `checkout my-feature` and `commit` to create single commit in your branch from several unfinished commits. After that, temporary branch can be deleted.

Comment: I'd qualify the "don't use amend" option: don't use it on published work. On unpublished work (local/personal branches) you should absolutely use it. (And if you have more than one personal repo, that does mean you'll use `push --force` to transfer your work around sometimes. That's fine.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Now I can keep my code safe and the commit logs clean.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way, the option --force-with-lease

```
 git push --force-with-lease
```

It will only force the update if nobody has pushed after you, or if you haven't pushed on another machine;. If you got a rejection you will then fetch/rebase before pushing again, so working in a more secure way.

From the documentation

> --force-with-lease alone, without specifying the details, will
> protect all remote refs that are going to be updated by requiring
> their current value to be the same as the
> remote-tracking branch we have for them.