# How to push to repo after doing 'git commit --amend'

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

I made a commit & pushed to repo. Later I modified the commit message by using `git commit --amend`, In the pop-up window I entered the new message. I could see the new message via `git log`. After all this process, my `git status` shows like this. I don't know how to push this change to repo.

```
On branch master
Your branch and `origin/master` have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit(s) each, respectively.
```

Expecting a feasible solution for this.

Comment: Are you okay with splitting the commit again and building on the already published (leaked?) head?

Comment: See [master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

Comment: If you can avoid amending commits once they've been pushed to a public place where other people can see them, you absolutely should. This goes for rebasing too.

Answer (score 28):

2012: If you are ok with modifying the history on the remote repo (as in, you just pushed that commit, and no new commits were made), you can try a

```
git push --force
```

However, do read first "[How do I push amended commit to the remote git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)": if anyone already pulled from that repo, he/she won't be happy.

An alternative is described in "[Git: pushing amended commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968281/git-pushing-amended-commits)".
As mentioned by [cpeisert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164465/cpeisert) in the comment "[`master` branch and '`origin/master`' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)" described your warning message.

---

2022: note that [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937476/6309) is safer than `git push --force`.

And you also have [`git push --force-if-includes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/6309) (Git 2.30+), which attempts to ensure that what is being force-pushed was created *after* examining the commit at the tip of the remote ref that is about to be force-replaced.