# Reset/revert a whole branch to another branches state?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset, git-revert

I have a branch *A* and a branch *B* (and some other branches).

Lets say *A*'s commit history looks like:

- commit 5
- commit 4
- commit 3
- ...

And *B*'s commit history:

- some other commit
- commit 4
- merge of other stuff from branch *C* (into branch *B*)
- commit 3
- ...

Basically what I want is to "delete" all changes made by the commits *some other commit* and *merge of other stuff from branch C* to branch *B*.

I want the working tree of branch *B* to be exactly the same like branch *A*'s working tree.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One way to achieve this is through `git reset`. While on branch `B` execute

```sh
git reset --hard A
```

Thereafter, branch `B` points to the head-commit of `A`. The `--hard` option resets the index and working tree so that all tracked files are reset to the version in branch `A`. The old HEAD commit-ID of `A` is stored in `.git/ORIG_HEAD` in order to allow undoing the change.

Alternatively - while not on branch `B` - you can delete branch `B` and re-created it like this:

```sh
git branch -d B     # delete branch B
git branch B A      # re-create branch B and let it point to the commit of branch A
```

Other than the first suggestion, this will leave the index and working tree untouched.

Comment: thanks. reset --hard A is exactly what I was searching for. However: how do I push this (resetted branch) back to origin? origin denies pushing, because of the diverged commits..

Comment: You can add the `--force` option to the `push` command to override the remote branch. But you should be well aware about the consequences as e.g. described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259585/other-consequences-of-git-push-force) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432788/git-push-force-behind-the-scenes).

Comment: Sometimes, when dealing with git, you need some `hard A` to cool the nerves.

Answer (score 15):

If you want your branch `B` to look exactly like branch `A`. You could just do a `reset --hard`

```
git checkout branch-B

git reset --hard branch-A
```

Be careful you will lose commits in this case. Your branch-B will look exactly like branch-A, whatever commits were made to branch-B, that were not present in branch-A, will be **lost**. Also if branch-B is shared with other people, its not recommended to perform this operation.

In that case you could try reverting the commits you don't want in branch-B

```
git revert <sha-of-"some other commit">
git revert <sha-of-"merge of other stuff from branch C (into branch B)">
```

The second commit looks like a merge commit so you might have to pass the parent as well.

```
 git revert <sha-of-"merge of other stuff from branch C (into branch B)"> -m1
```

Answer (score 14):

As others have shown it is true that a git `reset --hard` will make branch B look exactly like branch A. However, this will delete B's history. A different approach, which avoids this problem, is to create and apply a patch file:

```sh
git checkout A
git diff B > /tmp/AtoB.patch # Generate changes needed to make B match the current branch A
git checkout B
git apply /tmp/AtoB.patch # Update files to match the state of A
git add -A # Track any deleted or newly created files
git commit -a -m "Make B match A" # Commit the changes
```

Now we're not "rewriting history" so there will be no controversy when you push to origin. This approach has the benefit that the syncing is a discrete commit in B's history that could be reverted at any time. NOTE however that the commit history from branch A is lost in the translation.

> BTW: If you get an error about binary files, add the --binary flag to your diff command like this `git diff --binary B > /tmp/AtoB.patch`

Comment: handy **git alias** that will make the current branch match A: 'git patchtomatch A'
`[alias] patchtomatch = !DSTBR="$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)" && SRCBR="$1" && PATCHFILE="$(tempfile).patch" && (echo "Trying to make $DSTBR equal to $SRCBR" && git checkout "$SRCBR" && git pull && git diff --binary "$DSTBR" > "$PATCHFILE" && git checkout "$DSTBR" && git apply "$PATCHFILE" && echo "Now you can run:" && echo \\"  git add -A \\ \\ \\# to also track new and deleted files\\" && echo \\"  git commit -m \\'Make branch $DSTBR match $SRCBR\\'\\" && rm "$PATCHFILE") || rm "$PATCHFILE"`

Comment: @MrFT This is absurd. There's zero need for such a trainwreck of an alias.

Answer (score 8):

For completion, let's add this very simple way to achieve it :

```
git branch -f branchB branchA
```

It takes advantage of the fact that branches in git are mere pointers. This command just replaces the ref to the tip commit of one branch with another. No need to go into complex structure changes to build something you already have.

(See the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---force))

Answer (score 3):

I realize (very late, I admit) that OP in fact never asked to delete all of B's *history* but rather *changes*, so my first answer, like most others above, is indeed achieving the expected working tree but unfortunately it's *at the expense* of branch `B`'s history, which is lost.

So let's suggest here the plumbing way to **both preserve full history and achieve the exact tree you wanted to obtain**, with `git commit-tree` (see [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree))

```
# to be executed from branch B
git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -m "Reset to A" -p $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) $(git rev-parse A)^{tree})
```

**Explanation**

The `git commit-tree` command broken down :

```
git commit-tree -m <message> -p <parent> <tree>
```

1. `<tree>` needs here to be branch `A`'s tree, we'll get it with `$(git rev-parse A)^{tree}`.
2. `<parent>` must point to `B`'s tip :`$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`
3. then the above two parameters plus the message are used by the command to produce a new commit,
4. and finally `git reset --hard` sets current branch (`B`) on the fresh new commit returned by `git commit-tree`.

Looks convoluted at first, but a great tool.