# git - revert branch to look like master?

Tags: git, branch, git-reset, git-revert

I have two branches `develop` and `master`. There are lots of commits in develop that are not in `master` yet. Though I need to make `develop` branch look exactly the same as `master`. To preserve all changes that happened into `develop`, I will create new branch from `develop` so all those changes won't be lost.

But after doing "copy" of `develop`, how can I safely reset or revert to look like `master`?

I saw this: [Git: reset/revert a whole branch to another branches state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774194/git-reset-revert-a-whole-branch-to-another-branches-state)

So to reset, I can do:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard master
```

But the problem is `develop` branch is already pushed to remote and there others that had pulled `develop` already.

**Maybe there is safer way to do this using revert or some other means?** But I want to revert (if possible) in a way that would revert to `master` state, not manually selecting every commit, because some latest commits need to be kept in `develop` because they came from master (hotfixes).

So history of commits on `develop` looks something like this (most top means latest commit by date):

```
commit hotfix2 - in both develop and master
some other commits that are only in develop
commit hotfix1 - in both develop and master
some commits that are only in develop
all commits that came when develop was created from master
```

Comment: So, what you want to do is undo all commits that were only done in develop? (e.g. undo the “some commits“ and the “some other commits” from your history)

Comment: @poke Well yes, but is there some easier way than to go through all commits and pick the ones I need to undo? This is just a sample, in real case there are lots of commits that need to be undo and there are commits in between which need to be kept. With `reset`, it is easy, I can just specify branch and it will reset to look exactly like `master`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard process to undo commits in a non-destructive way is to use [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). This command basically takes the inversed diff of a target commit and tries to apply it. So you get a new commit that undoes all the changes.

In order to undo multiple commits at once, you can also specify a commit range. Given that you only have two ranges you would want to undo (those between those hotfixes), this would be actually manageable.

You can also use the flag `--no-commit`, or `-n`, to *not* automatically create a commit. This allows you to chain multiple `git revert -n <commit>` commands after another without creating a reverting commit for each. Then, when you’re done selecting all commits or commit ranges you want to undo, you can make a single commit that combines them all.

In your case, since you have another branch which has the exact (working directory) state you want to put your `develop` branch into, it is a lot easier to do that. All you have to do is to check out the working tree for `master` into your `develop` branch and commit that state onto the `develop` branch. You would do this using `git checkout master -- .`. Unfortunately, this will not work for paths that are unknown to the `master` branch. So if you added new files in the `develop` branch, those are kept and you would have to delete them separately.

Instead, we start a new branch off `master` (which then has the exact same content), and reset that branch so it is based on `develop` instead. That way, we keep the working directory state from `master` but a commit would be follow `develop` instead. Afterwards, we can fast-forward `develop` that one commit:

```
# checkout a new branch off master
git checkout -b new-develop master

# make a soft reset to develop
git reset --soft develop

# commit the changes
git commit

# get back to develop and fast forward
git checkout develop
git merge --ff-only new-develop
git branch -d new-develop
```

This will result in the same thing you would get by chaining `git revert -n` with all the commits that are exclusive to `develop`. There are a few other ways to reach that state, but that’s really the easiest.

Regardless of which way you use to get to this state, you should consider making a merge afterwards. The merge will not actually do anything (since both branches have the same content) but it will combine the branches in the history, so you see that they actually converge.

So assuming the history looks like this right originally:

```
                       master
                         ↓
* ------------ h1 ------ h2
 \              \         \
  * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *
                           ↑
                         develop
```

You would want to turn it into this:

```
                                master
                                  ↓
* ------------ h1 ------ h2 ----- M
 \              \         \      /  ↖
  * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- F   develop
```

`F` being the fix commit we created above. This assumes that you would want to merge `develop` into `master` (`git merge develop` while on `master`) and then fast-forward `develop` (`git merge master` while on `develop`) to start the development work fresh from that point. Of course, you could also do it in the other direction if you prefer that.

Alternatively, we can also do this merge `M` and the fix `F` in a single step. You would effectively merge `develop` into `master` and merge everything in the way that you end up with the contents of `master`. This would look like this:

```
                                master
                                  ↓
* ------------ h1 ------ h2 ---- FM
 \              \         \      /  ↖
  * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * ---/   develop
```

You can get there by hand like this:

```
# since we merge into master, we start there
git checkout master

# start the merge, but don’t attempt to fast-forward and do not
# commit the merge automatically (since we want to change it)
git merge --no-ff --no-commit develop

# reset the index that was prepared during the merge
git reset

# now checkout the files from master and commit the merge
git checkout master -- .
git add .
git commit
```

And actually, this is such a common scenario that [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) comes with a merge strategy that does exactly this. So instead of the above, we can just use the `ours` merge strategy and discard anything from the branch we merge into the current:

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours develop
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this, but it seems to not undo `develop`. It only undo files that were changed in both `master` and `develop`. But there are many files that are only added into `develop`, but not `master`. And those are kept. So when I finish checking out `develop`, and then when I merge `develop` into `master` it actually adds all those files into `master`. Am I missing something here? Do I need to just manually delete all those files and commit it?

Comment: Which solution did you try? The very last one (using the `ours` merge strategy) should definitely work; for the other ones, you may need a `git reset` before the `git checkout master -- .` (I forgot that). After the merge, `git diff <original-master>` should return nothing, and `git diff <original-develop>` should show many changes which are no longer on the current branch.

Comment: That’s odd, that should work (assuming that I have the correct idea of your history). Can you try the last option? If that doesn’t work, can you open a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and we can continue there?

Comment: Also third option third options with git merge ours, do not do anything to `develop` and when I go to `master` I see commits from `develop`, but no files from develop. Shouldn't this be done for `develop` instead of `master`? To me it looks that only the first option does anything to develop

Comment: Yes, the last option merges `develop` into `master` while discarding any changes. That way, you converge the history but preserve all the changes from `develop` (without keeping the content). This updates `master`, so afterwards you need to fast-forward `develop` to `master` (`git merge master`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116054/discussion-between-andrius-and-poke).

Answer (score 2):

Below command will get all files (except new ones added in current branch) from origin/master

```
git checkout origin/master .
```

Then, one can use git rm to remove the new files *for example*

```
git rm newfile
```