# How to push to remote after a git rebase?

Tags: git, github

Hi I successfully removed a bad commit using:
`git rebase -p 0df8fg5^ 0df8fg5`

I am working on the `master` branch.
However now when I:

`git push`

It gives:

```
To git@github.com:my_user/my_repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:my_user/my_repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

`git status` gives:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: **rule 1: don't rebase/amend commits that you already pushed somewhere.** If you still want to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3968449/520162

Comment: Alright, then what is the alternative?

Comment: you'll need to `-f`orce the push as the answers tell you.

Comment: Clearly, but that doesn't answer the question. You said `don't rebase ...` I'm asking what the alternative would be to remove a specific erroneous commit further back in history

Comment: If you don't want to force the push, you cannot remove a commit from history once you pushed it somewhere. However, you could `git revert` the single commit that was wrong. This introduces a new commit that reverts the changes of the wrong one but doesn't remove the wrong commit from history. This is safe to be pushed then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git push rejected after feature branch rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939977/git-push-rejected-after-feature-branch-rebase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's saying that you have diverged from master, because it appears to git as though there is a point where you have commits that `origin/master` doesn't have and `origin/master` has commits that you don't have. That point is the point at which you removed the commit from your local copy of `master` (The rebase changes the sha's of the following commits).

To fix this you have to *force push*. **BUT** by default, pushing pushes all your local branches to a branch with the same name in the remote, which means doing a force push could overwrite other people's changes.

You can change the default behaviour of git in this regard with a config setting:

```
git config --global push.default <setting>
```

where `<setting>` can be `upstream`, `current`, or `simple` to prevent pushing to all branches you have local versions of. The default before Git 2 is `matching` which has the overwriting behaviour I was talking about, whereas the default behaviour from Git 2 onwards is `simple`. Here's an excerpt from the git man-page describing what each of these settings actually does:

> - `current` - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
> - `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called @{upstream}). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).
> - `simple` - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch's name is different from the local one.
>
>   When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.
>
>   This mode will become the default in Git 2.0.

*[-- git-config man-page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)*

The command for force pushing is:

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to force the push

```
git push -f
```

If others are also using the remote's master branch this will surprise them a great deal. Not necessarily in a positive way.

Comment: What has your team member done before? What is the exact output of `git status` after the push?

Answer (score 2):

After a rebase, you need to generally do a force push to remote.

```
$ git push -f origin master:master
```

What this will do is forcibly update master without caring about fast-forwarding